# input for timestamp in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, date, timestamp, sql-insert

I am taking input in the below table as

```
insert into friendship values(&req_id,&sender_id,&receiver_id,'&sent_at');
```

But i dont't know what syntax I should type for timestamp in the input window. When I am typing like `2013-12-01 11-01-01`, it is not inserted.

```
create table friendship (
    req_id integer primary key,
    sender_id integer not null,
    receiver_id integer not null,
    sent_at timestamp
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Oracle function `TO_TIMESTAMP()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions193.htm) to convert a string to a `TIMESTAMP` datatype.

Consider:

```
insert into friendship values(
    &req_id,
    &sender_id,
    &receiver_id,
    TO_TIMESTAMP('&sent_at', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24-MI-SS')
);
```

This will allow an input like `2013-12-01 11-01-01`.